# How to maintain parse.com automatic user between application restarts?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Here is the scenario:

- Automatic user is enabled via `ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser()`
- I create an object, say a Todo from Offline Todo tutorial (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/OfflineTodos) and pin it:

```java
Todo todo = new Todo();
todo.setUuidString();
todo.setTitle("test");
todo.pinInBackground();
```

- It works fine for the first time
- Now close the app (not just send it to background, close it using Recent Apps button and swipe it off the screen)
- Run the app again. Here the exact same code above throws this exception:

cannot setReadAccess for a user with null id

Even though a workaround might be to sign-up the automatic user at some point before closing the app that's hardly the point of automatic users which are supposed to work offline plus there is no guarantee that the app won't be closed before our during sign-up process.

Saving the user to get an id is not an option too: not only its an online operation, you are not supposed to call save() on a user. According to documentations it should be signup() instead.

Even pinning the current user before creating other object didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you found a solution on your own yet for this, but I think this should work: At app start-up, when you enable automatic user creation:

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            // ...

            if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser()==null) {
                ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
                ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
            }

            // ...
        }
    }
```

This will (a) ensure that you always have a current user, and (b) if it is an anonymous user that user will persist through application restarts.

Note 1: saveInBackground() won't actually save the user to the server because the user does not have a username/password, but will persist the user.
Note 2: I haven't tested this fully but it should fix your situation.